# getting error Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidatorFactory

Tags: spring, hibernate-validator

I have a spring project. When i run i get the following error

```
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [javax/validation/bootstrap/GenericBootstrap.class] 
from Jar [jar:file:/D:/Personal%20Work/eclipse%2032%20Bit/workspace/Java%20EE/Spring
/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
/ch17_ImplementTheViewsForContactInformation/WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar!/] 
for annotations
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    ....
```

Here is my snippet of POM

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Beta2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate’s implementation of JSR-303. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- The JSR-303 Bean Validation API library. -->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
       <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0.GA</version> 
    </dependency>
```

Why i am getting this error ? I checked, i have this jar at location `C:\Users\basit.ahmed\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA`.

How can i solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a result of a bad download.  Delete the jar from your local repo and try again.

Comment: Right, can try listing the content of the jar (jar -tvf validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar) to verify if the jar is ok. I would assume using jar will fail as well.