# SpringMVC hibernate-validator java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ValidatorFactory

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, java-8, bean-validation

I know it is popular error and I try resolve this but I can't.
I tired use latest hibernate-validator and older version but this not helped me. I use tomcat7.

Error 500:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean] for bean with name 'validator' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/DispatcherServlet-context.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidatorFactory
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean] for bean with name 'validator' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/DispatcherServlet-context.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidatorFactory
```

My pom.xml:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.virnikandrapid</groupId>
<artifactId>microblog</artifactId>
<version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Database (H2) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.185</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- DataSource (mysql) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.30</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JPA Provider (Hibernate) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

DispatcherServlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true" validator="validator" />


<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resource/**"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.virnikandrapid.microblog"/>
<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
</bean>
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10240000"/>
</bean>
<bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
    <property name="order" value="-2"/>
</bean>
<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/definition/tile-definition.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
<property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource" />
</bean>


<jpa:repositories base-package="com.virnikandrapid.microblog.domain.repository"/>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://host.me:3306/amel3?characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
    <property name="username" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="psdd"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.virnikandrapid.microblog.domain"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

My jar's:

[jar's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T64dO.png)
[jar's part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EptPP.png)

Please help me ;)

Comment: Probably because the dependency `javax.validation:validation-api` is missing/not properly downloaded (from the screens i see that these are listed). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17043601/4516887 and http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|javax.validation|validation-api|1.1.0.Final|jar - Also try to refresh the dependencies and then rebuild the artifact and deploy again

Comment: I faced a similar problem, I tried all options nothing worked for me. then create a new project in IntelliJ IDE and copied required files to new projects. this fixed my issue. I am thinking it might be an IDE issue too where it is pointing old jars in the classpath or in the cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add this to your dependencies :

`<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: I added this dependency, removed ~/.m2 folder and used mvn clean but still nothing...

Comment: ìs the validation.jar visible to your classpath ? also when deploying to tomcat , are the dependencies being exported properly in the deployment assembly ?

Comment: Actually you want to use 1.0.0.GA of the validation-api, since you are using a Hibernate Validator 4.x release which aligns with Bean Validation 1.0. validation-api 1.1.0.Final is for Bean Validation 1.1 and aligns with the Hibernate Validator 5.x series. Also, the validation-api is a transitive dependency of Hibernate Validator, so it should be pulled in automatically. What's the output of `mvn dependency:tree` in your project?